# Ruby - reset and attribute that's not associated with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby

I have an attribute called `name`, complete with `attr_accessor` and I'm setting it's value in `initialize` :

```
def initialize
  @name = #code
end
```

I need to implement a reset method that resets the value of `@name`. The only way I can think of to do this is by using the exact same code I use in `initialize`. I've tried to look up a way of doing this but every method I've seen (eg `reload`) is only available for objects associated with ActiveRecord. Is there any way I can avoid the repetition of using the same code in two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to write the code. Ruby has no concept of "resetting" an attribute.

What ever `#code` is, you can move it to a method and invoke that method in `initialize`, and then define a `reset` that does the same thing.

```
class MyClass

  def initialize
    reset
  end

  def reset
    reset_name
  end

  private

  def reset_name
    @name = #code
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay, thanks @meager . It was worth asking :) I'll accept your answer when SO lets me.